# openstack heat doesn't recognize key_name parameter

Tags: openstack, private-key, openstack-heat

hy

i have an openstack deployed on my laptop. i'm trying to create a stack with heat.

i have created a keypair `openstack keypair create heat_key > heat_key.priv`
which is recognized by nova `nova keypair-list` give the following output :

```
+----------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Name     | Type | Fingerprint                                     |
+----------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| heat_key | ssh  | 0b:7a:36:20:e2:e3:19:3b:ab:a1:95:ac:67:41:67:d7 |
+----------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

this is my simple HOT template :

```
heat_template_version: 2013-05-23

description: Hot Template to deploy a single server

parameters:
  image_id:
    type: string
    description: Image ID
  key_name:
    type: string
    description: name of keypair to enable ssh to the instance

resources:
  test_stack:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      name: "test_stack"
      image: { get_param: image_id }
      flavor: "ds1G"
      key_name:{ get_param: key_name }

outputs:
  test_stack_ip:
    description: IP of the server
    value: { get_attr: [ test_stack, first_address ] }
```

when i try to create the stack

```
openstack stack create -t myTemp.hot --parameter key_name=heat_key --parameter image_id=trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1 test_stack
```

i get the following error

```
ERROR: Property error: : resources.test_stack.properties: : Unknown Property key_name:{ get_param
```

i have tried with different versions of templates but i get the same error

any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WORST part about the YAML file is, it is SPACE sensitive, so we need to be really careful while editing or copying conetent of HEAT templete. There is no space between "key_name" and "{" which is why it is failing.

> key_name:{ get_param: key_pair_name }

Just put `an extra space` between these and it will work.  I tested it :-)

> key_name: { get_param: key_pair_name }

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the parameter name `key_name` to some other name and execute it

```
heat_template_version: 2015-10-15

description: Hot Template to deploy a single server

parameters:
  image_id:
    type: string
    description: Image ID
  key_pair_name:
    type: string
    description: name of keypair to enable ssh to the instance

resources:
  test_stack:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      name: "test_stack"
      image: { get_param: image_id }
      flavor: "ds1G"
      key_name: { get_param: key_pair_name }

outputs:
  test_stack_ip:
    description: IP of the server
    value: { get_attr: [ test_stack, first_address ] }
```

Comment: @Mheni: Did you tested what I suggested ?

Comment: i just tested it `openstack stack create -t myTemp.hot --parameter keypair=heat_key --parameter image_id=trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1 test_stack`  and i get the same error   **ERROR: Property error: : resources.test_stack.properties: : Unknown Property keypair:{ get_param }**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by providing the details in parameters . PFB Sample script which worked for me.

```
heat_template_version: 2016-10-14

description: Admin VM - Test Heat
parameters:
  image_name_1:
    type: string
    label: Centos-7.0
    description: Centos Linux 7.0
    default: Centos-7.0
  network_id_E1:
    type: string
    label: 58e867ce-841c-48cf-8116-e72d998dbc89
    description: Admin External Network
    default: Admin
  network_id_E1:
    type: string
    label: 4f69c8e5-8f52-4804-89e0-2c8232f9f3aa
    description: Internal-1 Network
    default: SR-IOV Interface
  network_id_I2:
    type: string
    label: 28120cdb-7e8b-4e8b-821f-7c7d8df37c1d
    description: Internal-2 Network
    default: Internal-2
  KeyName:
    type: string
    default: IO_Perf_Cnt
    description: Name of an existing key pair to use for the instance
    constraints:
      - custom_constraint: nova.keypair
        description: Must name a public key (pair) known to Nova
resources:
  AdminVM1:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      availability_zone: naz3
      image:  { get_param: image_name_1 }
      flavor: 4vcpu_8192MBmem_40GBdisk
      key_name: { get_param: KeyName }
      networks:
        - network: { get_param : network_id_E1 }
```